# Get text from XPath of immediate child

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to retrieve up a product name from the following markup:

```html
<h2>
     <a href="https://example.com/item/ait-themes-anchor-wordpress-theme/">
             <span>AIT Themes</span> 
                   Anchor 
             <span>WordPress Theme for Campsites</span></a>
             <span class="version">2.0.0</span>
</h2>
```

I want to get the name of product. I am currently using the following xpath:

```
//a[@class="link-cover"]//parent::div/h2/a/text()
```

But I am getting the result that is inside the span tag too. This is unwanted.

```
[<Selector xpath='.//text()' data='AIT Themes'>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data=' Solitudo '>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data='WordPress Theme'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//text()' data='AIT Themes'>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data=' Spa '>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data='WordPress Theme'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//text()' data='AIT Themes'>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data=' SportClub '>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data='WordPress Theme'>]
[<Selector xpath='.//text()' data='AIT Themes'>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data=' Sushi '>, <Selector xpath='.//text()' data='WordPress Theme'>]
```

I tried to specify which element I want through the index.

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="link-cover"]//parent::div/h2/a/text()')[1]
```

But this does not work very well because this specific site has pages that vary in format, but the name of the product is always inside the a tag.

I tried to use the "not" xpath operator, but doesn't return anything.

```
//a[@class="link-cover"]//parent::div/h2/a/not(span)/text()
```

EDIT:
For reference, I'm calling xpath through scrapy as follows:

```py
    def parse_products(self, response):

        products = response.xpath('//a[@class="link-cover"]//parent::div/h2/a')

        for product in products:

            name = product.xpath('.//text()')[1].get()
            link = product.xpath(".//@href").get()

            yield {
                "product_name": name,
                "product_link": link,
                "product_developer": response.request.meta['developer'],
                "product_category": response.request.meta['category']
            }

        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//nav[@class="navigation pagination"]/div[@class="nav-links"]/a[@class="next page-numbers"]/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse_products, meta={
                "developer": response.request.meta['developer'],
                "category": response.request.meta['category']
            })
```

Comment: Is the product name "Anchor"? You haven't said...

Comment: I said I didn't want what was inside the <span> tag, which for elimination, only "Anchor" would be left.

Comment: Actually, not "Anchor", but "Anchor" and lots of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `//h2/a/text()[normalize-space()]`. Full XPath expression for your website :

```
//div[@class="new-post-display new-posts2"]//h2/a/text()[normalize-space()]
```

Output :

```
 Anchor 
 Aqua 
 Architect 
 Arctica 
 Aspiration 
 BandZone 
 Barcelona 
 BeachClub 
 Brick 
 BusinessFinder+
 ...
```

**EDIT** : Your XPath expression works in scrapy shell.

[image: Selectors]

Get the data :

[image: Extract]

I think the problem is in your spider code. You've posted this as a result :

```
[<Selector xpath='.//text()' data='AIT Themes'>,...
```

Replace in your spider `.//text()` with `./text()` and you should be OK.

Sidenote : if you want to use an index, fix your XPath accordingly :

```
response.xpath('//a[@class="link-cover"]//parent::div/h2/a/text()[1]')
```

Comment: I keep getting the same result. I'm using this xpath expression inside a web crawler using scrapy. Should I put the minimum reproducible code together with the question? I didn't put it in initially because for the scope of the question, about xpath, the information I put in is enough because the question is about xpath, not scrapy.

Comment: Another question, why would normalize-space in this case solve this problem? According to the MDN Firefox definition: "The normalize-space function strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string." There are actually a lot of unnecessary spaces, but this is not the real problem I asked in the question. The problem is to ignore the <span> tag and just capture the text that is directly inserted as an attribute of <a>.

Comment: OK. I've edited my answer. `normalized-space` is used just in case to ignore whitespace nodes.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your answer very well. I tried to change the code and received this error: ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression in .text() Look the line number 7: https://pastebin.com/h9DXzHU9

Comment: EDIT: I made a little mistake in line number 7, but the error still the same: https://pastebin.com/BZuBebbs

Comment: I just confirmed it. The problem is in the way xpath is being called by scrapy. https://pastebin.com/7xCBTj0a Is there any solution ?

Comment: I made a typo in my EDIT. Your line 7 should be `name = product.xpath('./text()').get()`